# prevent access to s3 buckets for sagemaker users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to add an IAM user for using sagemaker. I used the `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess` policy. But when I log in as this user I can see all of the s3 buckets of the root account and download files from them.

The [sagemaker documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html) states

> When attaching the AmazonSageMakerFullAccess policy to a role, you must do one of the following to allow Amazon SageMaker to access your S3 bucket:
>
> Include the string "SageMaker" or "sagemaker" in the name of the bucket where you store training data, or the model artifacts resulting from model training, or both.
>
> Include the string "SageMaker" or "sagemaker" in the object name of the training data object(s).
>
> Tag the S3 object with "sagemaker=true". The key and value are case sensitive. For more information, see Object Tagging in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.
>
> Add a bucket policy that allows access for the execution role. For more information, see Using Bucket Policies and User Policies in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.

This seems to be inaccurate the user can access s3 buckets lacking `sagemaker` in the name. How do I limit the access?

the full policy is below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*SageMaker*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*Sagemaker*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*sagemaker*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/SageMaker": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/sagemaker.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_SageMakerEndpoint",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "sagemaker.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the IAM User have any other IAM policies associated with them? Do they belong to any IAM Groups that have IAM policies? If you remove the above policy from them, can they still access other S3 buckets? There's a policy somewhere that's letting them do stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the sagemaker notebook wizard has you create a role that has limited s3 access. If I add this and the default `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess` the user is properly restricted. [image: Amazon make sagemaker role]

[image: choose iam roles]

Comment: But now a user can just opt not to choose a role when creating a notebook and still has full s3 access, because the default is to create a role with AmazonSageMakerFullAccess. How can we stop this?

Comment: what's the problem exactly?